# PHP Concatenate many variables and store them into one variable?

Tags: php

I would like to know if this is the correct way to Concatenate many dynamic variables and store them into one variable? The dynamic variables contain HTML. Some of them may, depending on earlier code, contain nothing.

Or are there alternatives?

```
    $specialproductmsg = $garminmsg .= $studdybuddymsg .= $baroncoursemsg .= $fircoursemsg .= $pilotworkshopmsg .= $cfirenewalmsg .= $flightsimmsg .= $xplane11msg .= $ltfcoursemsg;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall do

```
$specialproductmsg = $garminmsg . $studdybuddymsg . $baroncoursemsg . $fircoursemsg . $pilotworkshopmsg . $cfirenewalmsg . $flightsimmsg . $xplane11msg . $ltfcoursemsg;
```

And everything will be stored on     `$specialproductmsg`

To concatenate don't use `.=` in between the variables.

You can see more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Answer (score 1):

You could just store them in one variable to begin with.

Instead of all the separate variables like `$garminmsg` and `$studdybuddymsg`, you could assign the dynamic HTML strings to different keys of an array like

```
$html['garminmsg']
$html['studdybuddymsg']
// etc.
```

You'll be able to do the same things with `$html['garminmsg']` that you would with `$garminmsg`, and when it's time to output it (or assign the entire contents to another variable) you can use things like

```
$specialproductmsg = implode('', $html);
```

or

```
foreach ($html as $section) {
    echo $section;
}
```

and forgo all the messy concatenation.

Comment: I like this method but instead of using `''` I use `PHP_EOL` for better line breakings in the browser

Comment: @Sysix yeah, that definitely makes it easier to read the resulting page source if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate in PHP using `.`.

```
//assuming first initialization, use = to assign, . to concatenate vars
$specialproductmsg = $garminmsg.$studdybuddymsg.$baroncoursemsg;
//since init already, append additional concatenated vars
$specialproductmsg .= $fircoursemsg.$pilotworkshopmsg.$cfirenewalmsg;
$specialproductmsg .= $flightsimmsg.$xplane11msg.$ltfcoursemsg;
```

I split it into three lines for readability. `.=` appends while `.` concatenates.

`.=` is equivalent to a var `=` itself concatenating to something else:

```
$foo .= $bar;
//is equivalent to
$foo = $foo.$bar;
```